# subset rows by list of variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

context: 10 files. csv, each file contains an date frame with 5 columns: name, date of birth, sex, attitude, and result. On each line there is a name, date of birth, sex, attitude, and result.

problem: each attitude has a result. each attitude was exported on one line. soon, there are several lines for each registered attitude.

goal: to extract from each of the files, individuals who possess the set of attitudes recorded with their results.

```
ext {
atlist <- as.list(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8)
library(dplyr)
setwd("~/")
files_list <- list.files(x, full.names=TRUE)
dat <- data.frame()
fim <-  data.frame()
for (i in 1:10) {                                
    dat <- (read.csv(files_list[i]))
    dat <- dat %>% filter(attitude == "atlist")
    fim <- rbind(fim, dat)
  }
  fim
}
```

I'm struggling with this for some time. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Can you add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking because it's not clear what `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, etc. are, but if each of those represents the attitudes that you would like filtered, perhaps you would like to do the following:

```
atlist <- c(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8)
setwd("~/")
files_list <- list.files(full.names=TRUE)
fim <-  NULL
for (i in 1:10) {                                
    dat <- (read.csv(files_list[i]))
    dat <- dat[dat$attitude %in% atlist,]
    fim <- rbind(fim, dat)
}
```